# Setting properties for window installer such as Author, Description

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, installation

Hi I have problem with setting properties for window installer such as Author, Description...

Project for which I want create installer package is WPF app. I set assembly properties in WPF project.

[image]

I create new project Visual Studio Project -> Setup project and add WPF assembly.

Build this project and try run app.  As destionation folder I see:

C:\Program Files\Default Company Name\Spirit\

I suppose that Company name will be comapny name of assembly for which I created installation package.

I try find how set this projeties  in setup project but I can’t find way how can I set this properties on setup project.

If I try set properties of setup project I see this:

[image]

I use Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 28):

I think you are doing what I found myself doing for a while there, right click and choose properties brings up the Projects configuration properties, Build etc like you are getting.

I had my other "standard" properties window on auto hide, so I re pinned it and put it in its own window and then selecting the setup project brings up its "standard" properties.

See the screen shot below, hopefully it helps someone, this question isn't too recent

[image: Standard Properties]

Answer (score 0):

Most of this information is retrieved from the MSI Summary Information. So you can modify them by using a tool that can edit this information, for example Orca:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(VS.85).aspx